# Connecting to SQL Server 2008 of provider using connection string

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I just deployed my website on a remote server of the provider `somee.com`, but I can't manage to connect to my SQL Server database.

I attached the *.mdf and *.ldf files to the database I created on the provider side, which asked me to update my connection string with this (I concealed the id and password of course):

```
workstation id=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user 
id=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxxxxx;data source=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;persist security 
info=False;initial catalog=MoviesDBtest
```

Now, I know I have to update my Web.config file, but I just don't have a clue where to add these properties to my original tag:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="workstation 
 ID=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=dalya;pwd=02038800;data 
 source=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial 
 catalog=MoviesDBtest;Integrated 
 Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /><add name="MovieDBEntities" 
 connectionString="workstation ID=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user 
 id=dalya;pwd=02038800;data source=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;persist security           
 info=False;initialcatalog=MoviesDBtest;metadata=res://*/Models.MoviesDBModel.csdl|res://*/M
odels.MoviesDBMode
l.ssdl|res://*/Models.MoviesDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
connection string=&quot;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="MoviesDBEntities" 
connectionString="workstation ID=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user 
id=dalya;pwd=02038800;data source=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;persist security 
info=False;initial 
catalog=MoviesDBtest;metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://
*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection 
string=&quot;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="MoviesDataBEntities" 
connectionString="workstation ID=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user 
id=dalya;pwd=02038800;data source=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;persist security 
info=False;initial 
 catalog=MoviesDBtest;metadata=res://*/Models.MoviesDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MoviesDBMode
l.ssdl|res://*/Models.MoviesDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
connection string=&quot;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="WTFEntities" 
connectionString="workstation ID=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user 
id=dalya;pwd=02038800;data source=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;persist security 
info=False;initial 
 catalog=MoviesDBtest;metadata=res://*/Models.MoviesDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MoviesDBMode
l.ssdl|res://*/Models.MoviesDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
connection string=&quot;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="MovieDBEntities" 
connectionString="workstation ID=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user 
id=dalya;pwd=02038800;data source=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;persist security 
info=False;initial 
catalog=MoviesDBtest;metadata=res://*/Models.MoviesDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MoviesDBMode
l.ssdl|res://*/Models.MoviesDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
connection string=&quot;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="MoviesDBEntities1" 
connectionString="workstation ID=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user 
id=dalya;pwd=02038800;data source=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;persist security 
info=False;initial 
  catalog=MoviesDBtest;metadata=res://*/Models.MoviesDBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MoviesDBMode
l.ssdl|res://*/Models.MoviesDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
connection string=&quot;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MoviesDB.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Could someone please tell how to modify it?

Comment: I don't think you concealed your user id and password very well. Just sayin'

Comment: haha you're right. Not to worry, it's just tests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea about all the entity stuff you posted or. But now that you've attached your database at a host, you no longer need anything about AttachDBFileName, user instances, etc. For the application it would look like this (carriage returns added for readability):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="user id=dalya;pwd=02038800;
      data source=MoviesDBtest.mssql.somee.com;
      initial catalog=MoviesDBtest;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Someone else will have to translate the entity/model connection strings.

Comment: +1 plus I don't think you can have both `Integrated Security=SSPI;` and a `user id=:...;Pwd=....` in a connection string at the same time.....

Comment: @marc_s Right, that's kind of like trying to take the subway *and* a taxi downtown.

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't tried anything like that... in a lot of cases only one of the connection methods will be valid anyway, but I suspect the provider might complain about invalid connection string attributes before it got that far...

Comment: Ah - there: *If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be used.* - so in this case, there will be an attempt to use integrated security to connect to the database server - not a good idea in a hosted environment! (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

Comment: thanks, that worked. Now I'm going to have to figure out the entity/model strings as you said, since I'm getting the error "The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid."

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to put this.`<system.webServer> 
            <defaultDocument> 
                <files> 
                    <add value="index.aspx" /> 
                </files> 
            </defaultDocument> 
        </system.webServer>`